# access vba - grab the results in the code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on an access application and I am trying to do the following:
the user insert input to a search, and then I search in my db, and I want to manipulate the results (generate an html file and put the results in there).

so I have a form with one input, there the user insert something he wants to search.

then it redirects to another form, with following on_load code:

```
Private sub form_load()
    dim str as string
    set frm = screen.activeForm 'gets the last form
    str = frm!search 'the input the user entered
    task = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE (condition)" 'some query with the db and the input
    Me.recordSource = taks
end sub
```

this form gets the results and prints them.

now, I see the results on my form. but, what I want is: to get the results and manipulate them in the code, for example, make an array with all the results ids and not to print it to the user.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will let you connect vba to your database and get the data out:

```
Sub vbaRecords()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQLstr As String

Set db=CurrentDb

SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE (condition)" ' You'll need to flesh this out to have the same condition as you've used previously.
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(SQLstr)

' Then you can move around the recordset. Assuming you want to start at the beginning:
rst.MoveFirst

' Then you can access individual items
vbitem1 = rst!item1

' You can also loop through the different records, if there's more than 1 (your condition can narrow this down)
do until rst.EOF
    ' Grab items from each record in here and do something with them
rst.MoveNext
Loop

' Then close and end the connections
rst.Close
db.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should open a Recordset with your query, loop on it's results,and apply your logic within the loop.

For instance, you can call my sub below after your :

```
Me.recordSource = taks
For_Instance taks ' Call my sub and pass it your SQL instruction
```

And here's the sub in question that you purt in your form and containing your logic:

```
Private Sub For_Instance(strSQL As String)

    Dim DB As dao.Database
    Dim RST As dao.Recordset
    Dim lngID As Long
    Dim strMyField As String
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set DB = CurrentDb

    Set RST = DB.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If RST.BOF Then Exit Sub ' no records found, stop.

    ' If you want to know how many record you have prior to loop, do:
    RST.MoveLast
    lngCount = RST.RecordCount
    Debug.Print "There are " & lngCount & " to process."


    ' Let's loop on your recordset now...

    ' first, reposition on first record:
    RST.MoveFirst

    ' Then start to loop
    While Not RST.EOF

        ' This is where you do your stuff with the records
        ' You can grab the data that is in the current line of you recordset like this:
        ' RST!name_of_the_field
        ' name_of_the_field refers to your column names

        ' Suppose you have a column named ID with type long, to get the current ID, do:
        lngID = RST!ID

        ' Suppose you have a column named MyField with type string
        strMyField = RST!MyField

        ' and do whatever you want


        ' And finally you go to the next record and continue your stuff
        RST.MoveNext
        i = i + 1

    Wend

    ' When you arrive here, you have processed all your records
    MsgBox "All done, I have processed " & i & " records"

    'Close your recordset
    RST.Close

    'Clean your objects
    Set RST = Nothing
    Set DB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open a recordset using the same SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE (condition)
```

and browse the records as needed.

Comment: I am a bit noobie, any more specific explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the Recordset class. You can use it like this to get the results of the query into an object:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM results WHERE (condition)", dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges)
```

From there you can run through it, query and manipulate it as you like.